# Keyboard module hotkeys not working after locking windows

Tags: python, keyboard, hotkeys, global-hotkey

After locking windows then logging back in, the keyboard module is no longer working.

I have tried refreshing the hotkeys by unbinding and then rebinding them, but that does still not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

The default add hotkeys like this:

> ```
>   keyboard.add_hotkey("f6", hotkey_pressed)
> ```

no longer worked after I would press ctrl+alt+delete or windows+l.

I was able to solve this issue with this:

> ```
>  Keyboard.hook_key("f6", lambda e:hotkey_pressed(str(e)))
> ```

> ```
>  def hotkey_pressed(e):
>
>       if 'down' not in e: return
>       print('pressed')
> ```